# Hard Drive Start / Stop count & Firmware Update

Tags: hard-drive, firmware

I've got a 500GB Seagate Momentus XT hybrid drive that has done a great job since I bought it.

I've noticed that there's a lot of people on the internet complaining that their Momentus XT has tons of issues (freezes, weird noises, poor battery life), and Seagate have issued several firmware updates. The newest one is SD25. I'm still on SD22, the original firmware that shipped on the first production drives.

I haven't had these issues, although when I first bought it I did notice it audibly span up/down a lot, it stopped doing that after about a month. The SMART data for my drive shows that its had 4,513 power on hours, 1,095 power on cycles, 30,538 load cycles (!), and 36,222 start/stops (!) which seems to contradict that though, so maybe it has been spinning down, only doing so quietly so I didn't notice.

The start/stop and load cycle counts seem to suggest that the drive powers down once every 8 minutes, which seems excessive for its stay in two desktop replacement laptops which spend most of their time plugged in with Windows set to *never* spin down the hard drive.

Its rated for 600k start/stop cycles, but the SMART attribute already has a rating of 65. 2 months ago it only had 29k start/stop cycles. In two months its gained 7k start/stop cycles, compared to only 2k for the secondary drive.

Should I be worried about this?

Is it enough of a problem that I should be updating the firmware? (or should I just be thankful that I'm not having freezing issues and weird noises with my drive?)

Its a significantly higher amount of cycles per month than the other drive, but then again, its still going to take 15 years to hit the manufacturer's rated limit, so I'm not sure if its really something I should be worrying about, since by the time the warranty expires in 4 years I'll probably be using an SSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a rating of 600k cycles, and using 3500 a month, that means it will take 14 years to reach its rated lifetime.  Doesn't seem to be cause for concern.

Comment: I guess so. It worries me that there's such a massive difference between the two drives, but maybe i'm just being paranoid.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest official Seagate Momentus XT firmware update.  I believe it will stop the chirping/head parking your drive has been having. You can get it from [Seagate's KB](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/215451en)

Comment: **^^^ IMPORTANT!** As of 7/15/2013, SD26 is VERY obsolete. (SD28 is current) More importantly, Seagate appears to have *finally* come to its senses & realized that making end users beg, plead, and endure email delays for access to firmware updates does nothing to protect them from bricked drives, and gives malware authors more opportunities to social-engineer their way around UAC. You can download the latest version directly from Seagate.com at http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/215451en (link verified 7/15/2013)